# How to make use the Paypal Payouts API to make payments to nultiple people

Tags: node.js, paypal, payout

I am trying to execute a **PayPal** **Payout** on a **Node.Js** environment, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. The payment doesn't get made.

I think that I am not getting the parameters right, and, or maybe my code needs re-organizing.

Please help me wrap my head around it, and eventually start heading in the right direction?

Thank you all in advance.

**LOCALLY ON THE CLIENT BROWSER:**

```
<script>
  paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'production'
    // Set up the payment:
    // 1. Add a payment callback
    payment: function(data, actions) {
      // 2. Make a request to your server
      return actions.request.post('/my-api/create-payment/')
        .then(function(res) {
          // 3. Return res.id from the response
          return res.id;
        });
    },
    // Execute the payment:
    // 1. Add an onAuthorize callback
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
      // 2. Make a request to your server
      return actions.request.post('/my-api/execute-payment/', {
        paymentID: data.paymentID,
        payerID:   data.payerID
      })
        .then(function(res) {
          // 3. Show the buyer a confirmation message.
        });
    }
  }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

**ON THE NODE ENVIRONMENT**

```
const path = require("path");

var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var app = express();

var request = require("request");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

/** - - - - - - - */
var requestBody = {
    "sender_batch_header": {
        "sender_batch_id": "Payouts_2018_100007",
        "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
        "email_message": "You have received a payout! Thanks for using our service!",
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "note": "Your 1$ Payout!",
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "100.00",
            },
            "receiver": "john-doe@personal.example.com",
            "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_1",
        },
        {
            "note": "Your 1$ Payout!",
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "200.00",
            },
            "receiver": "business.example.com",
            "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_2",
        },
    ],
};

// Add your credentials:
// Add your client ID and secret
var CLIENT = "abc-def-ZAFupw-kq6-ghi";
var SECRET = "xyz-ns0xjKT0dkbpJrkvnkMG4ZUZEHd-mnop567";
var PAYPAL_API = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com";

var PAYOUTS_URL = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?";

// Set up the payment:
// 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button
app.post("/my-api/create-payment/", function (req, res) {
    // 2. Call /v1/payments/payment to set up the payment
    request.post(
        PAYPAL_API + "/v1/payments/payment",
        {
            auth: {
                user: CLIENT,
                pass: SECRET,
            },
            body: {
                intent: "sale",
                payer: {
                    payment_method: "paypal",
                },
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            total: "300.00",
                            currency: "USD",
                        },
                    },
                ],
                redirect_urls: {
                    return_url: "https://mighty-oasis-92039.herokuapp.com/",
                    cancel_url: "https://mighty-oasis-92039.herokuapp.com/",
                },
            },
            json: true,
        },
        function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            // 3. Return the payment ID to the client
            res.json({
                id: response.body.id,
            });
        }
    );
});

/** START PAYOUTS */

app.post("/my-api/execute-payment/", function (req, res) {
    // 2. Get the payment ID and the payer ID from the request body.
    var paymentID = req.body.paymentID;
    var payerID = req.body.payerID;
    // 3. Call /v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXX/execute to finalize the payment.
    request.post(
        `${PAYOUTS_URL}paymentID`,
        {
            auth: {
                user: CLIENT,
                pass: SECRET,
            },
            requestBody,
        },
        function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            // 4. Return a success response to the client
            res.json({
                status: "success",
            });
        }
    );
});
/** END PAYOUTS */

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 0):

The button code in your question is for checkout.js and v1/payments, both of which are deprecated integrations, and which are for *receiving* payments.

Your server side code is for Payouts, which is for *sending* payments from your own account.  These are entirely separate things.

---

If you want buyers to be able to directly pay another account, first integrate the current version of PayPal Checkout.

Server side 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order' are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

Pair those two routes that return JSON data with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

And in the create call, configure the `payee` who will receive the payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/